# Remove horizontal spacing between \makebox and \dotfill

Tags: boxes, dotfill, horizontal-spacing

I want to present some information in a format which has a scenario described then dotfill to a right aligned result. If the scenario+result would fill the line, I want it to break to the next line and dotfill the entire line with the result right aligned.

I can achieve this with `\makebox`, but that introduces unwanted spacing between the box and the dotfill so it isn't a continuous run of dots.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\begin{document}

\begin{description}
    \item This is some text \dotfill Result
    \item This is some text which almost fills a line so dotfill does not produce an output \dotfill Result
    \item This is some text which does fill the line and a break occurs but dotfill doesn't dot \dotfill Result
    \item I would prefer that if the text fills the line, dotfill fills the next line before the result \makebox[3cm]{\dotfill}\dotfill Result
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

[image: compiled ouput]

I've tried various combinations of `\unskip` and `\ignorespaces`, but they don't give the desired result. I can `\kern-3pt` the space away, but that feels hacky. I'd much prefer to generalise a solution to a command I can use instead of dotfill:

`\NewDocumentCommand\myDotfill{}{\makebox[3cm]{\dotfill}\MAGICSPACEKILLER\dotfill}`

Can anyone advise what I should put in a command to try to kill the unwanted horizontal space?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

a version of dotfill using a skip of minimum size 3cm rather than 0pt, and avoiding being discarded on a line break

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
%\ShowCommand\dotfill
\NewDocumentCommand\mdotfill{}{%
\mbox{}\nobreak\cleaders \hbox to .44em{\hss .\hss }%
%\hfill
\hskip 3cm plus 1filll
 \kern 0pt\relax} 
\begin{document}

\begin{description}
    \item This is some text \dotfill Result
    \item This is some text which almost fills a line so dotfill does not produce an output \mdotfill Result
    \item This is some text which does fill the line and a break occurs but dotfill doesn't dot \mdotfill Result
    \item I would prefer that if the text fills the line, dotfill fills the next line before the result \mdotfill Result
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks David! I know I'm not supposed to use the comments for just that, but I wanted to specifically thank you for leaving your working in.

I can see that you used `\ShowCommand` to find the code for `\dotfill`, and replaced `\hfill` in it with `\hskip 3cm plus 1filll` which does exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

For those instances where you want a full-width line at the end, insert a [`\parnopar`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/628979/5764) before `\dotfill`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\newcommand{\parnopar}{\parfillskip=0pt\par\parskip=0pt\noindent}

\begin{document}

\begin{description}
    \item This is some text \dotfill Result
    \item This is some text which almost fills a line so dotfill does not produce an output \dotfill Result
    \item This is some text which does fill the line and a break occurs but dotfill doesn't dot \par \dotfill Result
    \item I would prefer that if the text fills the line, dotfill fills the next line before the result \parnopar \dotfill Result
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks Werner - this works if I manually add it after compiling and realising that I need it, but David's answer above gives me a general solution that doesn't require any user intervention.